# covering an annulus with unit cubes

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, combinatorial-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Let $E>1$ and consider an annulus in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with outer radius $R=\sqrt{E}$ and inner radius $R=\sqrt{E-1}$.

How many unit cubes do I need to cover the annulus?

The area of a $2$-dimensional annulus does not depend on the outer and inner radius, so one could think that the number of needed cubes depends only on the dimension. However, for growing $E$, the width of the annulus becomes thinner and the length of the inner and outer circumference becomes longer. So it looks to me that the number of cubes grows with $\sqrt{E}$, but I don't really understand how. Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: The "thickness: of the annulus will be $\sqrt{E}-\sqrt{E-1}$ which will grow progressively smaller as $E$ increases so the cubes will overlap the edges of the annulus by increasingly greater amounts. However, the number needed to cover the annulus will grow as the perimeter grows.

Comment: Just drawing a few examples suggests that the number of cubes required is going to be on the order of four times the radius.

Comment: MathOveflow copy of the question: [How many unit cubes to cover an annulus?](http://mathoverflow.net/q/265466)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $(\sqrt{E}-\sqrt{E-1})^2 = E^2+(E-1)^2-2\sqrt{E}\sqrt{E-1} ≤ E^2+(E-1)^2 < 1$.
This means the thickness of the annulus is always less than the width of the unit cube. This means the most efficient way to cover the annulus will be with a "chain". In other words, a collection of cubes that only intersects with the cube before and after it.

As $E$ grows, the thickness tends to $0$ while the curvature also tends to $0$, so the most efficient cover becomes a collection of diagonal cubes as drawn below.[image]

The perimeter will have a length of $2\pi r = 2\pi\sqrt{E}$. The length of $n$ cubes will be $n\sqrt{2}$ (because they have been placed diagonally). Hence the number of cubes needed is about $n=2\pi\sqrt{E}/\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{2}\pi\sqrt{E} \approx 4.44\sqrt{E}$.

Note that this is an approximation, and it holds for large $E$.

Comment: Hi @shanye2020 , thank you for the answer and the picture! Now I understand. Just one last thing, if I want my cubes to have sides parallel to the coordinate axes, then I can anyway follow your guideline but I will need more of them. Right?

Comment: Yes exactly. My answer is the "ideal case" which you get closer and closer to as E gets larger, but in reality you will generally need a few more cubes.